# Nuxt JS don't run routes function if domain is X

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I've got a Nuxt JS 2.12.2 project with a custom routes function in my config and a custom `dir` for generating my project! I'd like to use Netlify but I need a way of disabling this routes function if I'm on a netlify server? Any suggestions? I'm running in `universal` mode as well and have `dotenv` installed!

```js
/*
** Build directory
*/
generate: {
  dir: 'dist-next',
  routes: function () {
    return axios.get(process.env.BLOG_API)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data.blogs.map((blog) => {
        return '/posts/view/' + blog.title
      })
    })
  }
}
```